# Soql on multiple dates

Tags: soql

I want to query on the task for multiple dates
eg,

```
date d3 = system.today().addDays(3);
Select Id, Subject, WhoID, ActivityDate, OwnerId 
     from Task 
     where IsClosed = False and ActivityDate = :d3 
           and Subject ='Follow up Opportunity' 
     order By ActivityDate ASC;
```

This above code works fine
now i would expand this to query for

```
date d7 = system.today().addDays(7);
date d15 = system.today().addDays(15);
```

Now how will i change this soql for all the dates matching,d3,d7,d15.  Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use an OR:

```
Select Id, Subject, WhoID, ActivityDate, OwnerId from Task where IsClosed = False 
        and (ActivityDate = :d3 Or ActivityDate = :d7 Or ActivityDate = :d15) 
        and Subject ='Follow up Opportunity' order By ActivityDate ASC;
```

Comment: Or you can use IN operator.

Comment: Can anyone give me sample for IN, i get a error with IN.  I tried -Select Id, Subject, WhoID, ActivityDate, OwnerId from Task where IsClosed = False and (ActivityDate IN :d3,:d7) and Subject ='Follow up Opportunity' order By ActivityDate ASC];  Thanks Phil that works.

Comment: GOT IT! select Id, Subject, WhoID, ActivityDate, OwnerId from Task where IsClosed = False and ActivityDate IN (:d3, :d7) and Subject ='Follow up Opportunity' order By ActivityDate ASC

Comment: Yes, IN is less typing as you've managed to work out :)